# Как загрузить файл на сервер? Где хранить полученный файл?

Tags: java, spring

Пишу на сервер на Java, фрэймворк Spring, использую хостинг Heroku.

На сервер отправляется mp3 **файл**(если важно, что файл mp3, а не другой, то дайте знать, конкретизирую вопрос, пока буду спрашивать про загрузку любого файла, не обязательно mp3) , его нужно **принять** и **сохранить**.

**Вопрос:**
Как принимать файл на сервере? Где полученный файл сохранить?

Я пользуюсь хостингом Heroku и я вообще не уверен, что на нём можно удобно хранить файлы.
Возможно, уже существует что-то по-типу firebase для хранения файлов и сервер вообще не понадобиться, если это так, то подскажите такой сервис.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как грузить читаем тут: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload
Как хранить. Если файлов немного, или они не большого размера, можно в базу складывать. Так будет проще их искать и отдавать клиенту назад, например. Плюс в Heroku не надо будет парить голову о файловой системе.